# Use two monitors over one displayport

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

My colleague has a laptop with one DisplayPort, but he wants  to attach two (HDMI) monitors to it.  I've seen adapters that can split the signal over two monitors (with the addition of DisplayPort to HDMI adapters which is fine).

However the devices I have found say that they either clone the screen or extend over the desktop.  Is there a way to do this that will allow windows to recognise each monitor as a separate screen?

Comment: I fear not: a splitter works by making the graphics card believe that only one monitor is connected, so both monitors receive the same signal. If you have a separate VGA output, this _may_ be independent, depending on the laptop hardware. The only way to get two independent HDMIs is to use a USB-to-HDMI adaptor.

Comment: Unfortunately the laptop only has one external monitor connection.

Comment: I had never thought of using the USB ports.

Comment: Ivan Viktorovic's solution is an interesting answer, but note that Windows will still see only one monitor, albeit a very wide one, and you need to check that the laptop graphics card handles this resolution.

Comment: Hmm, might be the only option though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need a external graphic card with 2 output ports. Something like this (http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/digital_se/)